# Setting up Neo4j shell tools and import graphml in community version 2.3.0 [Windows]

Tags: shell, neo4j

I am having the Neo4j community version 2.3.0 installed on my windows machine.I am trying to install neo4j-shell tools in my windows machine.I tried copying the jar files and its not helping. Is there a limitation of this feature in community version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit, you just have to put them in the right directory.

It works best with the zip distribution on windows. Then you can just follow the readme.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing. What should the file structure look like?

<neo4j_base>/lib/neo4j-shell-tools-3.0/*

or should the contents of the folder neo4j-shell-tools-3.0 be up a level? Any way to know if they get "installed" correctly?